# Assert given text is not present in Drop Down Combo Box

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I had to automate scenario where i get First Name and email address , which i had stored then i need to assert that value with drop down box that its not present.

Here is HTML code for my Page

```
<select id="Customer" name="Customer" class="valid">
<option value="raj777@gmail.com">123123123  (raj777@gmail.com)</option>
</select>
```

It contained multiple entries ,

I need to verify that my given text does not exist in it.

I tried this but it does not works

```
assertNotEquals(fname+" "+em, driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Customer']")).getText());
```

Thanks In Advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below process:

1. Get the text of each element in the dropdown ('option' elements)
2. Strote the values in a list or array of string.
3. See the list or array contains your Name & mail id value.

or if u want to assert only, then in for-each loop of the array or list:
Add t

1. he assert statement in try-catch block.
2. In catch block, each time execution comes to this block, increase an integer.
3. After the fr-each loop, check the integer value is equal to yor list or array size.

Code sample for the first scenario:

```
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".trb_outfit_sponsorship_logo_img"))
        .click();
    System.out.println(dri.findElement(
        By.cssSelector(".trb_outfit_sponsorship_logo_img")).getSize());
    List<WebElement> dropDownValues = dri.findElements(By
        .xpath("//select[@id='Customer']"));
    ArrayList<String> dropDownValuesasText = null;
    for (WebElement eachValue : dropDownValues) {
        dropDownValuesasText.add(eachValue.getText());
    }
//  boolean result = dropDownValuesasText.contains("Your FirstName & Email value");
    //It will pass if your value is present in drop down
    assertNotEquals(dropDownValuesasText.contains("Your FirstName & Email value"), true);
```